# The toolbar for Android Studio IDE is missing

Tags: android, ide

I am a student trying to learn android programming and after decades of downloading this IDE, I am quite disappointed that upon searching everywhere I can't seem to find any working solution to restore my Toolbars and my Status Bars.

I have tried...

1. Restarting the IDE
2. Un-checking and checking `View > Toolbar` and `View > Status Bar`

Andddddd nothing seems to change nor be fixed. Thank you!

Comment: That is unusual. Last resort, try to reinstall Android Studio

Comment: I am not sure if the icon in left-bottom corner helps...

Answer (score -3, accepted):

try:

1. press shift+F12.
2. press ctrl+shift+F12.
3. goto settings - Appearance and Behavior - menu and toolbar - click restore defaults

Comment: Shift + F12 hides the app tree window.

Answer (score 1):

View->Appearance -> Toolbar(checkbox)